# How to fix the error message: "Type mistmatch" inferred type is MutableState<List<Task>> but Int was expected"

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

Working with ViewModels for the first time, so a little bit lost here. I have defined my viewmodel like so:

```
data class Task(
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    val isCompleted: Boolean
)

class TaskViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // A list to hold our tasks
    var taskList = mutableStateOf(
        listOf(
            Task("First", "Complete homework", "Finish math and science assignments", false),
            Task("Second", "Go for a run", "Run for 30 minutes in the park", false),
            Task("Third", "Read a book", "Start reading 'The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes'", false)
            // Add more tasks as needed
        )
    )
```

And then have tried to call it in a lazy column so it displays all items in my ViewModel, but the error "Type mistmatch" inferred type is MutableState<List> but Int was expected"

```
fun OverviewScreen(
    navController: NavHostController,
    viewModel : TaskViewModel = viewModel()
) {
//    val viewModel = TaskViewModel.viewModel
    val viewModel: TaskViewModel = viewModel()

            LazyColumn {
            items(viewModel.taskList) { task ->
                // Display each task in your list
                Text("Task: ${task}")
            }
        }
```

Not sure how to fix it, any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

So, the `items` in `LazyColumn` can accept either an Int (to repeat a composable that amount of times) or a List of items (to repeat a composable for every item in the list), however you're passing a MutableState<List> and `items` does not know how to get data from that, so your problem here is "how do I get the data from the MutableState"
and there are mutliple ways to achieve that, I will include the simplest:

solution nr 1. using `.value` will grab the list out of the MutableState

```kotlin
items(viewModel1.taskList.value) { task ->
    // Display each task in your list
    Text("Task: ${task}")
}
```

solution nr 2. using `by` in your view model to allow all references to get the value NOT the mutableState

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

data class Task(
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    val isCompleted: Boolean
)

class TaskViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // A list to hold our tasks
    var taskList by mutableStateOf(
        listOf(
            Task("First", "Complete homework", "Finish math and science assignments", false),
            Task("Second", "Go for a run", "Run for 30 minutes in the park", false),
            Task("Third", "Read a book", "Start reading 'The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes'", false)
            // Add more tasks as needed
        )
    )
}
```

```kotlin
LazyColumn {
   items(viewModel1.taskList) { task ->
       // Display each task in your list
       Text("Task: ${task}")
   }
}
```

Solution nr 3. using .observeAsState (will react to possible changes in the list)

```kotlin
class TaskViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // A list to hold our tasks
    var taskList = mutableStateOf(
        listOf(
            Task("First", "Complete homework", "Finish math and science assignments", false),
            Task("Second", "Go for a run", "Run for 30 minutes in the park", false),
            Task("Third", "Read a book", "Start reading 'The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes'", false)
            // Add more tasks as needed
        )
    )
}
```

```kotlin
fun OverviewScreen(
    navController: NavHostController,
    viewModel : TaskViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val taskList by viewModel.taskList.observeAsState(initial = emptyList()) 

    LazyColumn {
            items(taskList) { task ->
                // Display each task in your list
                Text("Task: ${task}")
            }
        }
}
```